# Overcoming 255 character limit when copying and transposing

Tags: excel, vba, range, transpose, copying

Basically in cells B42 and B43 I have more than 255 characters and my code breaks and gives RUN type error mismatch 13.

when I am running the following line:

```
    CopyTranspose wb.Sheets("Apple").Range("B17:B46"), shtDest.Cells(pasteRow, "R")
```

I get an  mismatch error in here:

```
Sub CopyTranspose(rngCopy As Range, rngDest As Range)
rngDest.Resize(rngCopy.Columns.Count, rngCopy.Rows.Count).Value = _
Application.Transpose(rngCopy.Value)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Google you will find that `Application.Transpose` has several odd limitations. But you can write your own `TransposeArray` function and see if that works better.

```
Public Function TransposeArray(myarray As Variant) As Variant
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim Xlower As Long, Xupper As Long
    Dim Ylower As Long, Yupper As Long
    Dim tempArray As Variant

    Xlower = LBound(myarray, 2)
    Ylower = LBound(myarray, 1)
    Xupper = UBound(myarray, 2)
    Yupper = UBound(myarray, 1)
    ReDim tempArray(Xlower To Xupper, Ylower To Yupper)
    For x = Xlower To Xupper
        For y = Ylower To Yupper
            tempArray(x, y) = myarray(y, x)
        Next y
    Next x
    TransposeArray = tempArray
End Function
```

And just use it like `Application.Tanspose`

```
Sub CopyTranspose(rngCopy As Range, rngDest As Range)
    rngDest.Resize(rngCopy.Columns.Count, rngCopy.Rows.Count).Value = _
        TransposeArray(rngCopy.Value)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to copy and transpose a range, then this will do:

```
wb.Sheets("Apple").Range("B17:B46").Copy
shtDest.Cells(pasteRow, "R").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
```

Or if want to copy only values without formats then

```
shtDest.Cells(pasteRow, "R").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
```

EDIT:
The issue may be with `Application.Transpose(rngCopy.Value)` as transpose inputs array or range of cells, not values.

Comment: I suspect that this does nothing else than `Application.Transpose` does and therefore *might* have the same issue? But at least worth a test.

Comment: I've just tested with 500+ chars in one cell, it works. No need to transpo

Comment: And I tested `Application.Transpose` with 500+ chars and it worked too. So that's meaningless because that's not what limited the OPs transpose even if the OP stated this in his question. There is no 255 Chars limit in `Application.Transpose` at all (must have been something else).

Comment: Just for your interest: `rngCopy.Value` actually **is** an array: `Debug.Print VarType(rngCopy.Value)` outputs `8204` which means `vbArray+vbVariant` according to [this list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/vartype-function). So it is an array of type variant.